# Why does UITableView contentOffset change when using segmented control?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a `UITableView` which has a segmented control in its navigation bar. I am using the same table view to show 3 different sets of data, based on the selected index of the segmented control. I am now trying to preserve the scroll position for each segment option, so that it appears that there is one table for each segment option (i.e. the results of each selection have independent scroll positions).

To do this, I am storing one `CGPoint` variable for each state, which is *set* to the `contentOffset` when the selected segment index changes. The variable is *used* to set the table view's content offset upon segment change.

However, it seems like the `contentOffset` value changes when the selected segment index changes without any visible change to the position within the table. It is like the 0-position of the content offset is moving, which makes my stored values now wrong.

When my controller contains the following methods:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // set up the view here...        

    print(tableView.contentOffset)
}

@IBAction func selectedSegmentChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(tableView.contentOffset)

    // code to change the data shown in the table view...
}
```

I get the following logged when the view loads:

> (0.0, 0.0)

but after changing the segment I get:

> (0.0, -64.0)

All states show the table view scrolled to the exact same position, that is - at the top.

This behaviour is preventing me from being able to store the scroll position properly, as the 'meaning' of the content offset seems to be changing.

---

Edit: the content offset is in fact being adjusted between `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()`, most likely due to a content *inset*. So I am now storing the content offset value the first time `viewDidAppear()` is called.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is usually caused by a property on the view controller. Setting it to `false` should fix it.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

It can also be set from the storyboard. Just select the view controller and uncheck `Adjusts scroll view insets`.

Comment: Thanks - when I disable the _Adjusts Scroll View Insets_ option, I get `(0,0), (0,0)` in the log, which does suggest that that fixes the problem. However, this view controller is linked to from a navigation controller, so when that option is disabled the top result in my table is hidden under the navigation bar. Should I set the insets manually instead?

Comment: Either you do that or you change your logic to work with auto adjustments on, whatever seems more convenient.

Comment: How would I change the logic to solve the problem whilst keeping auto adjustments on? Is there a way to trigger a recalculation of the `contentOffset` so I can accommodate for the -64 adjustment? Or is there a way to determine what the adjustment will be?

Comment: Aha. Leaving auto adjustments on, I can get the proper starting offset by accessing it in `viewDidAppear()` rather than `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the tableview estimatedRowHeight fix the problem 
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = Cell_Row_Height`

Comment: This made it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just now, and it seems this problem is consistent with UITableView in several scenarios.
My problem was caused when my UITableView had a headerView. A headerView is not the same as Header in section, it's a property of class UITableView and has to be frame based. My problem was caused when I my headerView's height was larger than:
`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].height;` I also had a ContentInset set to the normal `statusBarHeight + 44.0f` but after `reloadData` was executed on my tableView, the tableView would adjust it's ContentOffset automatically.
My solution was, that considering the ContentOffset was set by UITableView to make sure the beginning of my list would be visible. I would set my tableView to scroll to the beginning after `reloadData` was executed.
Here is my code:

```
self.headerView = [ProgramDetailsHeaderView new];
    self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [Utilz deviceWidth], [ProgramDetailsHeaderView headerHeightWithModel:self.model]);
[self.headerView setDelegate:self];

self.tableView = [UITableView new];
self.tableView.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraint = NO;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(_statusBarHeight + 44.0f, 0, [Utilz deviceBottomNotch] + 10, 0);
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
// TableView Constraints...

[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [weakSelf.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
}];
```

It's not the most standard answer, I will update my answer here when I find a better way.